# Visual Studio Code Python Conditional Statement problem

Tags: python, if-statement, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm new to programming and I'm currently learning Python through LinkedIn and I'm stuck at on one of the sample codes

```
def main():
    a, b = 1, 10
    if(a < b):
        st = "x is LESSER than y"
    print(st)
```

It's not even showing any error messages so I'm confused right now. (My interpreter is Python 3.7.4)

Comment: Are you calling `main()`?

Comment: don't use braces `()` for simple if-boolean-expressions, this is not Java/C++/JavaScript/C#

Answer (score 0):

You just created a function. You need to call the function to get executed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a variable, you can directly print unless it's absolutely necessary.
Call the function `main()`

```
def main():
    a, b = 1, 10
    if a < b:
        print("a is LESSER than b")

main()
```